# Is it possible to do something when certain url loads?

Tags: java, android, events, webview, load

I'm coding my first android "app", and kind of cheating, since I'm using a WebView to display what would be the main "application".

I found that the app is generally faster by rendering the backgrounds as ImageViews rather than loading them from the HTML code.
I have a ImageView that acts as the app's background and loads from the beginning, and is 'behind' the WebView(the WebView background is transparent).

But once the user presses enter on a text field, and is sent to another web page within the WebView, I'd like to get rid of the first background ImageView and load a new one, so that the previous one doesn't slow it down. So I guess I'd have to **detect some sort of load event, and do something with that. However, I've been looking in the documentation, and I've found nothing. I don't even know where to start. Is there any way to do this?** Thanks.

Here is my code, if it is of any use (but I don't think it's really relevant).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        mWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);


        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if((mWifi != null && mWifi.isConnected()) || (mMobile != null && mMobile.isConnected())) {

            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    findViewById(R.id.splash).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                }
            });
            mWebView.loadUrl(got_url);
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    findViewById(R.id.splash).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error-nointernet.html");
        }

    }
```

**What I ended up doing, thanks to Zafar:**

```
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.equals(certainUrl)) //url returns last requested URL.
            {
                findViewById(R.id.background0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.background1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have got is that you want to load the background image once the webview starts loading.
If it is the situation , you can use

```
onPageStarted
```

and set the image here.
Check this [link](http://javatechig.com/android/progressbar-while-loading-webview) if you can get some more solutions.If the requirement is anything else, please do reply.

Though you have done what you wanted, I would just like to add this method, if it helps you in other situations like this.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("abcd://")) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I think I explained it quite poorly. So first, the app loads, and loads an ImageView(the background) and a WebView. This is alright, but then, in the first loaded URL at the WebView, there's a field asking for user's input. Once the user submits (through html), and is redirected to the next page, I'd like to make the first background be gone and load a new one(or just make the first background be gone, for starters, ha).

Comment: Nevermind, I'm sorry, this is the right answer for the purpose, I still don't understand Java completely. Turns out onPageStarted (or onPageFinished), returns the URL that was last requested, and from there on, I used if statements. The code I used is on my post. Thank you very much!